# Removing row from ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, sidebar, android-viewholder

Total nube here. I'm trying to remove a row from a Viewholder that is being used as a sidebar menu in an Android app.

One of the menu items returns an "EMPTY_LABEL" text. I can set the text to invisible but I'd rather remove the row entirely. Any ideas on how I do this?

Code below - would really appreciate your help!

```
        ViewHolder holder;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        APMenuItem currentItem = mData.get(position);
        Integer rId = getResources().getIdentifier("sidebar_label_" + currentItem.getKey(), "string", APBaseInnerActivity.this.getPackageName());

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_profile, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    holder.textView.setText(APApplication.getUserInfo().getDisplayName());
                    holder.textView.setHeight(APDimensions.convertDpToPixel(60, APBaseInnerActivity.this));
                    holder.avatar = (DrawerRoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                    holder.pendingImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pending_image);
                    holder.pendingBackground = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pending_background);

                    holder.pendingImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.pendingBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if( APApplication.getUserInfo().getAvatarUrl() != null ) {
                        holder.avatar.setImageUrl(APApplication.getUserInfo().getAvatarUrl());

                        if ( !APApplication.getUserInfo().getIsAvatarApproved() )
                        {
                            holder.pendingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.pendingBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_2_copy_2);
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_bottom, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    if( rId != null ){
                        holder.textView.setText(getResources().getString(rId));
                    }
                    else{
                        holder.textView.setText("EMPTY_LABEL");

                    }
                    holder.textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
                    holder.textView.setHeight(APDimensions.convertDpToPixel(40, APBaseInnerActivity.this));
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if( type == 2 ){
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            if( rId != null && rId != 0){
                holder.textView.setText(getResources().getString(rId));
            }
            else{
                holder.textView.setText("EMPTY_LABEL");
            }

            holder.circleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            holder.textView.setHeight(APDimensions.convertDpToPixel(50, APBaseInnerActivity.this));

            if (currentItem.getCount() > 0) {
                Integer cnt = currentItem.getCount();
                holder.circleView.setText(cnt.toString());
                holder.circleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.circleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView circleView;
    public DrawerRoundedImageView avatar;
    public ImageView pendingImage;
    public ImageView pendingBackground;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So are you asking how to remove the TextView that would display the empty value?

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of a ViewHolder. ViewHolders are used to store view references, to avoid calling `findViewById()` every time a new item appears.

Views in adapter views are reused. Which means, ViewHolders too. If you remove the TextView from one, it will be removed in others that reuse the same view and viewholder.

Simply programatically hide/show it in `getView()`. It is a common practice, nothing wrong with it. If there are more differences than just this one view, create a separate layout and another view type.

Edit.

In your case, hiding and showing your TextView would look like this.

```
if( rId != null ) {
    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.textView.setText(getResources().getString(rId));
} else {
    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks LukeJanyga! How would I hide/show it in a getView? Do I do it here and do I set up a separate function

Comment: Added some code for your case. Of course, you can break your code into smaller functions to increase readability.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Luke